# Docker and webpack bundle generates locally but not in container

Tags: django, reactjs, docker, webpack

## Can't get webpack to bundle react.js inside docker.

**My webpack configs and frontend bundle properly. The issue has to do with docker integration.**

When I run webpack before the docker container is up, or while the container is up, webpack generates bundles and they are copied into the container. This works and I could develop this way, but it feels sloppy.

Instead, I want npm run build to run webpack in production mode inside the docker container. That way it generates bundles on its own if I just say docker-compose build and up.

I already have a docker container with a django backend working. All I need is for webpack to use babel to transpile the react code in djangoproj/static/js and move it to djangoproj/static/bundles. Once the file is bundled to that folder the rest on the django side works and the page is rendered.

It is worth noting that I don't get errors other than a 404 because the bundle isn't there. My output in the console shows that webpack uses babel to transpile and then bundles the code.

However, after a docker ps and a docker exec on the django container, the bundles are not generated. Nor is node_modules being installed in the /app/ dir. The node modules install fine in the the /tmp/ dir but are unable to be copied to /app/.

Another concern or question is, should I be handling the bundling of this in a separate container? To me it seems like it would just be easier to keep it in the django container, it's only running webpack to bundle. So I don't want another container in terms of overhead if not necessary, right? I would imagine because it would have to be copied over to the static folder in the django container another separate container for the bundling would be worse.

Thanks for any suggestions.

#### Here are my configs attempting to manage this:

1. Webpack.config.js

```
var path = require("path");
var webpack = require('webpack');
var BundleTracker = require('webpack-bundle-tracker');

module.exports = {
  mode: 'development',
  context: __dirname,

  entry: {
    'index': './sam_site/static/js/index.js',
    'about': './sam_site/static/js/about.js',
    'project': './sam_site/static/js/project.js',
  },

  output: {
      path: path.resolve('./sam_site/static/bundles'),
      filename: "[name]-[hash].js",
  },

  plugins: [
    new BundleTracker({filename: './sam_site/webpack-stats.json'}),
  ],
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: ['babel-loader']
      }
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['*', '.js', '.jsx']
  }

};
```

2. package.json

```
{
  "name": "sam_site",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "It's my site.",
  "main": "index.js",
  "directories": {
    "doc": "docs"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --host 0.0.0.0 --inline --content-base .",
    "build": "webpack --config webpack.config.js --progress --colors --mode production",
    "watch": "webpack --config webpack.config.js --watch --mode development"
  },
  "author": "Samuel Piecz",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.5.5",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.5.5",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.6",
    "webpack": "^4.39.2",
    "webpack-bundle-tracker": "^0.4.2-beta",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.7"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.9.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.9.0"
  }
}
```

3. .babelrc

```
{
  "presets": [
    "@babel/env",
    "@babel/react"
  ]
}
```

4. local.yml same as compose.yml

```
version: '3'

volumes:
  local_postgres_data: {}
  local_postgres_data_backups: {}

services:
  django: &django
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./compose/local/django/Dockerfile
    image: sam_site_local_django
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    env_file:
      - ./.envs/.local/.django
      - ./.envs/.local/.postgres
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    command: /start

  postgres:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./compose/production/postgres/Dockerfile
    image: sam_site_production_postgres
    volumes:
      - local_postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
      - local_postgres_data_backups:/backups
    env_file:
      - ./.envs/.local/.postgres

  redis:
    image: redis:5.0

  celeryworker:
    <<: *django
    image: sam_site_local_celeryworker
    depends_on:
      - redis
      - postgres
      
    ports: []
    command: /start-celeryworker

  celerybeat:
    <<: *django
    image: sam_site_local_celerybeat
    depends_on:
      - redis
      - postgres
      
    ports: []
    command: /start-celerybeat

  flower:
    <<: *django
    image: sam_site_local_flower
    ports:
      - "5555:5555"
    command: /start-flower
```

5. django Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.6-alpine

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

RUN apk update \
  # psycopg2 dependencies
  && apk add --virtual build-deps gcc python3-dev musl-dev \
  && apk add postgresql-dev \
  # Pillow dependencies
  && apk add jpeg-dev zlib-dev freetype-dev lcms2-dev openjpeg-dev tiff-dev tk-dev tcl-dev \
  # CFFI dependencies
  && apk add libffi-dev py-cffi \
  # Translations dependencies
  && apk add gettext \
  # https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#dbshell
  && apk add postgresql-client \
    # NPM
    && apk add --update npm

# Npm & webpack goodness
WORKDIR /app
COPY . /app
CMD npm install 
CMD npm audit fix 
CMD npm run build 

# Requirements are installed here to ensure they will be cached.
COPY ./requirements /requirements
RUN pip install -r /requirements/local.txt

COPY ./compose/production/django/entrypoint /entrypoint
RUN sed -i 's/\r$//g' /entrypoint
RUN chmod +x /entrypoint

COPY ./compose/local/django/start /start
RUN sed -i 's/\r$//g' /start
RUN chmod +x /start

COPY ./compose/local/django/celery/worker/start /start-celeryworker
RUN sed -i 's/\r$//g' /start-celeryworker
RUN chmod +x /start-celeryworker

COPY ./compose/local/django/celery/beat/start /start-celerybeat
RUN sed -i 's/\r$//g' /start-celerybeat
RUN chmod +x /start-celerybeat

COPY ./compose/local/django/celery/flower/start /start-flower
RUN sed -i 's/\r$//g' /start-flower
RUN chmod +x /start-flower

WORKDIR /app

ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoint"]
```

6. .dockerignore

```
.*
!.coveragerc
!.env
!.pylintrc
!.babelrc
node_modules
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `volumes:` are breaking this setup.  Remove the line that bind-mounts content into `/app` in your container.

The Dockerfile sequence you show here will create an image that's copied your local source tree into `/app` and run `npm run build` on it.  This happens before most of the settings in `docker-compose.yml`, including the `volumes:`, get considered.  Then Compose starts a container that takes that image and bind-mounts the current directory over `/app`, hiding everything that happened during the build.

If you need a live-development environment, I'd suggest using your host system tooling directly (Python virtual environments, `npm run start`); this works just fine and avoids all of the complications that Docker adds here.

---

I would not add a separate container to do build-time tasks.  Doing these tasks in a Dockerfile makes more sense, or for things that have very few host dependencies (like Webpack) just running them directly on the host.

One trick that might help for cases like this is using a [multi-stage build](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/): have multiple parts in your Dockerfile that separately package the application and its UI, then combine them together.

```
FROM python:3.6-alpine AS wheel
...
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
RUN pip wheel

FROM node:12 AS webpack
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
RUN npm install && npm run build

FROM python:3.6-alpine
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=wheel /app/dist/wheel/myapp-*.whl .
RUN pip install myapp-*.whl
COPY --from=webpack /app/dist dist
COPY ./compose/... .
CMD ["/app/entrypoint"]
```

To the extent that you need C library dependencies, the build phase needs to install `-dev` packages like you've shown above, but the final image only needs to install the corresponding library package, not a full C toolchain.

Comment: Thanks David. I ended up removing the /app/ volume. I moved the COPY and the RUN for NPM towards the bottom of my Dockerfile, right before ENTRYPOINT. Looking into the multi-stage build now.